# How to open chrome devtools using code, like codeSandbox’s debugger feature

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, edge-devtools

[image]
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-react-autoplay-forked-4hf362?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A1%2C1

Like this button opens the developer tools, which is amazing. How is it done?

Comment: I had a quick look. It's not opening Chrome dev tools per se. It's an iframe. if you click on the settings button at the top right of Chrome you can then open more tools -> dev tools and then open the real dev tools and inspect the embedded one.

Comment: That's right, it looks exactly like the browser's developer tools. Thank you so much.